# Dump Hardware Registers from Volatile Pointer

Tags: c, arm

Say I have a structure mapped to a set to hardware registers that can change at any time.

e.g.,

```
typedef struct
{
    int  register1;
    char register2;
    ... (varying sizes, etc) ...
    int  registerX;
} registers_t;
```

And I'm defining regs as a volatile pointer to the base of the

e.g.,

```
#define regs (* (volatile registers_t *) ADDR_OF_REGS)
```

I'm trying to dump the regs at a specific time and save it off to an array storing the history of the registers.

e.g.,

```
registers_t register_history[5];
```

I understand that memcpy can't/won't allow casting a volatile * to const * because it's undefined behavior.

e.g., I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
memcpy(&register_history[0], regs, sizeof(registers_t));
```

Is there any way to copy the registers to memory without explicitly debouncing and saving each individual register?

Thank you for your help.

**Edit:**

Since I do not have sufficient reputation to answer my question until 8hrs after I posted, the question, I'll post the answer here for now:

Because I know that the registers will not change when I'm trying to capture the data, I can cast the ADDR_OF_REGS to void * and use memcpy.

e.g.,

```
memcpy(&register_history[0], (void *)ADDR_OF_REGS, sizeof(registers_t));
```

Comment: I think I may be able to memcopy straight from the address.. using memcpy(register_history[0], (void *) ADDR_OF_REGS, sizeof(registers_t)).... but that won't garauntee intended behavior...

Comment: What do you mean by "guarantee intended behavior"?  What do the registers represent (e.g. I/O, interrupts, etc.)?

Comment: Yes this is an embedded system and the registers represent I/O, interrupts, status, etc.  The registers can change at any given time (I was thinking debouncing may be necessary), but I guess when I'm trying to dump the registers, I should know that the registers won't change, therefore using memcpy is valid.

Comment: I'm no expert on ARM chips, but I thought that hardware usually debounced that kind of stuff.  It would seem awfully primitive if it didn't.  I would say just cast ADDR_OF_REGS to void *, as in your first comment, and use memcpy.

Answer (score 0):

using structures across compile domains is risky business.  pointing at memory/registers, etc is a "compile domain".

second, memcpy is simply going to read the registers sequentially and copy them sequentially, there is no magic in trying to do this with structures and memcpy that you cant just do yourself.  If for example these are 32 bit registers and aligned you can do better than memcpy....just do it yourself.

To copy 8 32 bit registers for example:

```
.globl myregcopy
myregcopy:
  push {r4,r5}
  ldmia r0!,{r2-r5}
  stmia r1!,{r2-r5}
  ldmia r0!,{r2-r5}
  stmia r1!,{r2-r5}
  pop {r4,r5}
  bx lr
```

call it with

```
myregcopy(base_add_of_registers,base_add_of_destination_ram);
```

memcpy shifts gears from bytes to halfwords to words then cruises often using four words per instruction then shifts back down to a halfword and byte before stopping (as needed, but the check code is there) so you will out perform memcpy and wont have to deal with these compiler problems getting in the way.

You have to verify with the hardware folks, a four word ldm or stm or an ldrd/strd can/will cause 64 bit transctions not 32 bit transactions if your core has a 64 bit bus.  If the register hardware does not state that the registers are accessible in pairs with 64 bit transactions you may only get one of the two registers decoded and on the bus with 32 bits of garbage.  so you need to know if this is a core with a 32 bit bus or 64 bit bus and if the I/O hardware or whatever you are capturing, handles the transactions properly.  If it doesnt change the code to something like this:

```
.globl wordcopy
wordcopy:
  ldr r3,[r0],#4
  str r3,[r0],#4
  subs r2,r2,#1
  bne wordcopy
  bx lr
```

called with

```
wordcopy(regbase,destmembase,numregs);
```

Not necessarily faster than memcpy, could be faster, same or a little slower, if you have to use this function because you cant handle 64 bit register reads against 32 bit registers then you cant use mempcy so there is no speed comparison, this is as good as it gets.

No matter what you are still responsible for the assumption that the registers wont change. which is also a risky assumption as you have no clue how long this copy is going to take unless you take a few extra measures.  and even then the copy time can vary.